# Can I return an API response without waiting on other external API calls in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-async

Is this the correct way to use `@Async` in Spring Boot?

```java
@Service
class someServiceImpl {
...
  public someResponseDTO getUsers(int userId) {
   // Do some logic
   ...
   // Call external API with another service method from another service impl
   anotherService.emailUserInTheBackground(userId);
   return someResponseDTO;
  }
...
}
```

```java
@Service
public class AnotherService {
  @Async
  public void emailUserInTheBackground(int userId) {
    // This might take a while...
    ...
  }
}
```

Since `emailUserInTheBackground()` has `@Async` annotation and `void` return type, does it block the line `return someResponseDTO` at all?

All I wanted is to return the response to the caller without waiting because `emailUserInTheBackground()` takes too long to complete and isn't directly tied to the response object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that is the correct way to run a task in the background, you can mimick the thread blocking behavior by introducing a delay.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
       SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class);
    }
}
```

then you need to mark the emailUserInTheBackground method with `@Async` annotation.

```
@Service
class AnotherService {

    @Async
    public void emailUserInTheBackground(int userId) {
       try {
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
          System.out.println("Print from async: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Now add one more logger after a method call, you'll see `getUsers(...)` call completing first in a different thread even though the emailService thread is blocked for 10 seconds.

```
anotherService.emailUserInTheBackground(userId);
System.out.println("Print from service: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

you can also use CompletableFuture to run a task in the background.

```
 public someResponseDTO getUsers(int userId) {
   // some other task
   ...
   // Call external API with another service method from another service impl
   CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> anotherService.emailUserInTheBackground(userId)) 
   return someResponseDTO;
  }
```

Comment: I would say spring events would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant behavior of `@Async` is documented in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async):

> You can provide the `@Async` annotation on a method so that invocation of that method occurs asynchronously. In other words, the caller returns immediately upon invocation, while the actual execution of the method occurs in a task that has been submitted to a Spring `TaskExecutor`.

In the case you're describing, since the `emailUserInTheBackground` method is annotated with `@Async` and Spring's asynchronous method execution capability is enabled, the `emailUserInTheBackground` method will return immediately, and the call will be processed in a separate thread.  The `someResponseDTO` value will be be returned from the `getUsers` method while the `emailUserInTheBackground` method continues to be processed in the background.